# How do those against the traditional monepiscopacy deal with Ignatius of Antioch?

Tags: ecclesiology, authority, bishops, ignatius-of-antioch

It's often claimed that 'Ignatius is the first to believe in the monepiscopacy' (that a bishop runs a church region with the assistance of presbyters/elders) or that 'churches were simply run by a plurality of elders.' However, don't his letters (written ~15 years after the book of Revelation) **assume this is the episcopacy is what all the churches (both East and West) already had?**

For the sake of brevity, I'll just cite some of what he says.

### The church in Ephesus...

> It is therefore befitting that you should in every way glorify Jesus Christ, who has glorified you, that by a unanimous obedience "you may be perfectly joined together in the same mind, and in the same judgment, and may all speak the same thing concerning the same thing," 1 Corinthians 1:10 and that, being subject to **the bishop** and the presbytery, you may in all respects be sanctified. (*Ad Ephesios*, cap. 2)
>
> ... Wherefore it is fitting that you should run together in accordance with the will of your bishop, which thing also you do. For your justly renowned presbytery, worthy of God, is **fitted as exactly to the bishop as the strings are to the harp.** (*Ad Ephesios*, cap. 4)

### The church in Magnesia...

> Since, then, I have had the privilege of seeing you, through **Damas your most worthy bishop,** and through your **worthy presbyters Bassus and Apollonius,** and through my fellow-servant the deacon Sotio, whose friendship may I ever enjoy, inasmuch as he is **subject to the bishop as to the grace of God, and to the presbytery** as to the law of Jesus Christ, [I now write to you]. (*Ad Magnesios*, cap. 2)

### The church in Tralles...

> For, since you are subject to **the bishop** as to Jesus Christ, you appear to me to live not after the manner of men, but according to Jesus Christ, who died for us, in order, by believing in His death, you may escape from death. It is therefore necessary that, as you indeed do, so without the bishop you should do nothing, but should **also be subject to the presbytery,** as to the apostle of Jesus Christ, who is our hope, in whom, if we live, we shall [at last] be found. It is fitting **also that the deacons,** as being [the ministers] of the mysteries of Jesus Christ, should in every respect be pleasing to all. For they are not ministers of meat and drink, but servants of the Church of God. They are bound, therefore, to avoid all grounds of accusation [against them], as they would do fire. (*Ad Trallios*, cap. 2)
>
> ...In like manner, let all reverence **the deacons** as an appointment of Jesus Christ, and **the bishop** as Jesus Christ, who is the Son of the Father, and **the presbyters** as the sanhedrin of God, and assembly of the apostles. Apart from these, there is no Church. (*Ad Trallios*, cap. 3)

### The church in Rome...

> Pray, then, do not seek to confer any greater favour upon me than that I be sacrificed to God while the altar is still prepared; that, being gathered together in love, you may sing praise to the Father, through Christ Jesus, that God has deemed **me, the bishop of Syria,** worthy to be sent for from the east unto the west. It is good to set from the world unto God, that I may rise again to Him. ... I write to the Churches, and impress on them all, that I shall willingly die for God, unless you hinder me. I beseech of you not to show an unseasonable good-will towards me. Allow me to become food for the wild beasts, through whose instrumentality it will be granted me to attain to God. I am the wheat of God, and let me be ground by the teeth of the wild beasts, that I may be found the pure bread of Christ. (*Ad Romanos*, cap. 2-4)

### The church in Philadelphia...

> Take heed, then, to have but one Eucharist. For there is one flesh of our Lord Jesus Christ, and one cup to [show forth ] the unity of His blood; one altar; **as there is one bishop, along with the presbytery and deacons,** my fellow-servants: that so, whatsoever you do, you may do it according to [the will of] God. (*Ad Philadelphios*, cap. 4)

### The church at Smyrna...

> See that you all follow the bishop, even as Jesus Christ does the Father, and the presbytery as you would the apostles; and reverence the deacons, as being the institution of God. Let no man do anything connected with the Church without the bishop. Let that be deemed a proper Eucharist, which is [administered] either by the bishop, or by one to whom he has entrusted it. Wherever the bishop shall appear, there let the multitude [of the people] also be; even as, wherever Jesus Christ is, there is the Catholic Church. It is not lawful without the bishop either to baptize or to celebrate an Agape [meal]; but whatsoever he shall approve of, that is also pleasing to God, so that everything that is done may be secure and valid. (*Ad Smyrnios*, cap. 8)

### Question

How do those who think the Catholic/Orthodox/Anglican/traditional view of the bishopric was not apostolic answer this?

Thanks in advance.